# Simple Car Animation Acceleration Too Slow

Tags: unity, physics, 3d, car

I am trying to make a very simple car animation where using the arrow keys, I can make a car move around. I am using wheel colliders and some code that goes like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Car_My : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    public float Motorforce, Steerforce, Brakeforce;
    public WheelCollider FR_L_Wheel, FR_R_Wheel, RE_L_Wheel, RE_R_Wheel;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
 
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Motorforce;
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Steerforce;
        print(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
 
        RE_L_Wheel.motorTorque = v;
        RE_R_Wheel.motorTorque = v;
 
        FR_L_Wheel.steerAngle = h;
        FR_R_Wheel.steerAngle = h;
 
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            RE_L_Wheel.brakeTorque = Brakeforce;
            RE_R_Wheel.brakeTorque = Brakeforce;
        }
 
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            RE_R_Wheel.brakeTorque = 0;
            RE_L_Wheel.brakeTorque = 0;
        }
 
        if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 0)
        {
            RE_L_Wheel.brakeTorque = Brakeforce;
            RE_R_Wheel.brakeTorque = Brakeforce;
        }
        else
        {
            RE_R_Wheel.brakeTorque = 0;
            RE_L_Wheel.brakeTorque = 0;
        }
       
    }
}
```

When I do this, the car moves but it accelerates too slowly. I changed all the values but I cannot get it to start at a faster speed. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Tried multiplying your v float by some value for the motor torques?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help.